# Problem with JavaScript destructuring understanding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I expect from the following JavaScript I will get [1,2,3,4] but I get undefined.

```
const {
  speakers: {
    datalist: { xxx },
  },
} = {
  speakers: {
    datalist: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
};
console.log(xxx);
```

Comment: You want `datalist: xxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
datalist: { xxx },
```

You're telling JS to put the `xxx` property of `datalist` into a standalone variable named `xxx`. But no `xxx` property exists on the `[1, 2, 3, 4]` array.

It'd work if the code was like this:

```js
const {
  speakers: {
    datalist: { xxx },
  },
} = {
  speakers: {
    datalist: {
      xxx: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
  },
};
console.log(xxx);
```

Or:

```js
const {
  speakers: {
    datalist
  },
} = {
  speakers: {
    datalist: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
};
console.log(datalist);
```

But this sort of nested destructuring is very difficult to read. Consider avoiding it so that these sorts of problems don't crop up:

```js
const obj ={
  speakers: {
    datalist: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
};
const { datalist } = obj.speakers;
console.log(datalist);
```

Comment: Or `const { speakers: { datalist: xxx } } = obj` or `const xxx = obj.speakers.datalist`